# C++ Output Parameter Causes Memory Leak

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, visual-c++, interface

I am working on a C++ project based on COM, My Code has a function with an out parameter which takes an object as input and assigns a new instance of a class into it. But when I used CRT Debugging I found some memory leak in the function, Here is the code of the function.

```
bool __stdcall FluentCompositor::CreateCompositionHost(HWND hwnd, ICompositionHost** compositionHost)
{
    if (compositionHost != nullptr)
    {
        *compositionHost = reinterpret_cast<ICompositionHost*>(new CompositionHost(hwnd));
        if (compositionHost != nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function takes an object of `ICompositionHost` and initialize it with `CompositionHost` object, Where should I need to free the memory to avoid memory leak.

I Call the function using ComPtr, but still there is memory leak

```
ComPtr<ICompositionHost> host;
compositor->CreateCompositionHost(hwnd,host.GetAddressOf());
```

The Complete Code:

***FluentCompositor.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "ICompositionHost.h"
#include "IFluentCompositor.h"
#include "CompositionHost.h"
#include "FluentCompositor.h"

FluentCompositor::FluentCompositor() :ref(1)
{
}

ulong __stdcall FluentCompositor::AddRef()
{
    return (++ref);
}

ulong __stdcall FluentCompositor::Release()
{
    if (--ref == 0)
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    return ref;
}

HRESULT __stdcall FluentCompositor::QueryInterface(REFIID iid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
    if (iid == IID_IFluentCompositor || iid == IID_IUnknown)
    {
        *ppv = (void*)this;
        AddRef();
    }
    else
    {
        *ppv = NULL;
    }
    return (*ppv == NULL) ? E_NOINTERFACE : S_OK;
}

HRESULT __stdcall CreateFluentCompositor(void** compositor)
{
    if (compositor != nullptr)
    {
        *compositor = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new FluentCompositor());
        if (compositor != nullptr)
        {
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    return E_FAIL;
}

bool __stdcall FluentCompositor::CreateCompositionHost(HWND hwnd, ICompositionHost** compositionHost)
{
    if (compositionHost != nullptr)
    {
        *compositionHost = reinterpret_cast<ICompositionHost*>(new CompositionHost(hwnd));
        if (compositionHost != nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

***MainWindow.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.h"

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    const wchar_t className[] = L"Fluent Compositor";

    WNDCLASS wc = {
        .lpfnWndProc = WndProc,
        .hInstance = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(&__ImageBase),
        .hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW),
        .lpszClassName = className,
    };

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP, className, L"Fluent Compositor Sample", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, wc.hInstance, nullptr);
    if (hwnd == nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    CreateCompositionEffect(hwnd);

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

bool CreateCompositionEffect(HWND hwnd)
{
    auto fluentCompositorLib = LoadLibrary(L"FluentCompositor.dll");
    if (!fluentCompositorLib)
    {
        return false;
    }

    CreateCompositor = (CreateFluentCompositor)GetProcAddress(fluentCompositorLib, "CreateFluentCompositor");
    if (!CreateCompositor)
    {
        return false;
    }

    CreateCompositor(&compositor);
    if (compositor == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ComPtr<ICompositionHost> host;
    compositor->CreateCompositionHost(hwnd,&host);
    return true;
}

LRESULT __stdcall WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

***MainWindow.h***

```
#pragma once
#include "IFluentCompositor.h"

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;

ComPtr<IFluentCompositor> compositor;

typedef BOOL(__stdcall* CreateFluentCompositor)(IFluentCompositor** compositor);
CreateFluentCompositor CreateCompositor;

bool CreateCompositionEffect(HWND hwnd);
LRESULT __stdcall WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
```

Comment: You should free the memory when you stop using it. It seems like you don't want to destroy the object in this function so the issue of the leak is somewhere else, more specifically where `compositionHost` goes out of scope

Comment: but i am passing ComPtr<ICompositionHost> object to the function as argument,so ComPtr frees it right?

Comment: `ICompositionHost` appears to be a COM interface. COM interfaces are reference counted. You free the object implementing that interface, when the reference count reaches zero. That's (presumably) implemented in `CompositionHost`. To make forward progress you have to stop thinking wrong: Your function **doesn't** *"take an object of `ICompositionHost`"*. It receives the address of a pointer to the `ICompositionHost` interface.

Comment: So to remove memory leak i need to free the object that i created using new CompositionHos(), am i right

Comment: The memory leak is the *least* of your issues. There are far more serious issues you would need to address. Like using C++' allocator to [move memory across DLL boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries). Or blindly letting C++ exceptions cross an ABI boundary. Or not properly reporting errors, and just leaving an `[out]` parameter uninitialized. Like, there's so much wrong, it's hard to even make out where to start.

Comment: Is `CompositionHost` *yours* ? As in, are *you* implementing it? if so, is the reference counting properly being managed by your implementation of `IUnknown`, or are you using an ATL kit class to handle that for you? COM interface reference counting isn't rocket science, but it is as easy to screw up as it is to get right. Also. if you invoke your `CreateCompsitionHost` method multiple on the *same* `host` smart pointer instance without an intermediate `Release` you absolutely *will* leak memory, since any prior interface pointer being hosted will not be properly released.

Comment: The CompositionHost Class is mine, I Created it.

Comment: Let me post the full code

Comment: I am not much familiar with C++ or COM, most of the docs about com seems to be more complicated

Comment: I am actually trying to learn COM, the project is just for test purpose, i am just trying to figure out the COM Stuff, do you have any sample project that you can refer, it might help a lot. Thank you

Comment: @IInspectable you told com was simple, i am still struggling to fix a memory leak, could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `reinterpret_cast` (and type-casts in general) is simply wrong.  If your classes implement the correct interfaces, there is no need to cast them manually (except maybe in `QueryInterface()`), the compiler will perform the *correct* conversions implicitly for you.

Also, you are not checking the return value of `new` correctly.  Or, for that matter, handling the possibility that `new` throws an exception on failure by default, not returns `nullptr`.  If you want a `nullptr` on falilure, use the `nothrow` version of `new` instead.

Also, when using `ComPtr`, should should be using its overloaded `operator&` rather than its `GetAddressOf()` method.  Especially if the `ComPtr` already holds an interface. `GetAddressOf()` will not release the interface (that is why there is a separate `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()` method), but `operator&` will.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <new>

HRESULT __stdcall FluentCompositor::QueryInterface(REFIID iid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
    if (!ppv) return E_POINTER;

    if (iid == IID_IFluentCompositor)
    {
        *ppv = static_cast<IFluentCompositor*>(this);
        /* alternatively:
        IFluentCompositor *comp = this;
        *ppv = comp;
        */
    }
    else if (iid == IID_IUnknown)
    {
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(static_cast<IFluentCompositor*>(this));
        /* alternatively:
        IFluentCompositor *comp = this;
        IUnknown *unk = comp;
        *ppv = unk;
        */
    }
    else
    {
        *ppv = nullptr;
    }

    if (!*ppv)
        return E_NOINTERFACE;

    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}

// similar for CompositionHost::QueryInterface() ...

HRESULT __stdcall CreateFluentCompositor(void** compositor)
{
    if (!compositor) return E_POINTER; // not E_INVALIDARG
    // make sure FluentCompositor has a refcount of 1 when created!
    *compositor = static_cast<IFluentCompositor*>(new(std::nothrow) FluentCompositor);
    return (*compositor) ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
}

bool __stdcall FluentCompositor::CreateCompositionHost(HWND hwnd, ICompositionHost** compositionHost)
{
    if (!compositionHost) return false;
    // make sure CompositionHost has a refcount of 1 when created!
    *compositionHost = new(std::nothrow) CompositionHost(hwnd);
    return (*compositionHost);
}
```

```cpp
ComPtr<ICompositionHost> host;
compositor->CreateCompositionHost(hwnd, &host);
```

Alternatively, consider using `ComPtr` internally when creating your objects, eg:

```cpp
#include <new>

HRESULT __stdcall CreateFluentCompositor(void** compositor)
{
    if (!compositor) return E_POINTER; // not E_INVALIDARG
    // make sure FluentCompositor has a refcount of 0 when created,
    // as the ComPtr constructor will increment it!
    ComPtr<IFluentCompositor> obj(new(std::nothrow) FluentCompositor);
    return (obj) ? obj->QueryInterface(IID_IFluentCompositor, compositor) : E_FAIL;
}

bool __stdcall FluentCompositor::CreateCompositionHost(HWND hwnd, ICompositionHost** compositionHost)
{
    // make sure CompositionHost has a refcount of 0 when created,
    // as the ComPtr constructor will increment it!
    ComPtr<ICompositionHost> obj(new(std::nothrow) CompositionHost(hwnd));
    return ((obj) && (obj->QueryInterface(IID_ICompositionHost, reinterpret_cast<void**>(compositionHost)) == S_OK));
}
```

It is a good idea to have your objects start with a reference count of 0 rather than 1, because they don't know if they are going to be used with interface pointers or object pointers (if they are even used with pointers at all).  Don't increment an object's reference count unless it is actually assigned to an interface pointer that is `AddRef()`'ed and needs to be `Release()`'d.

Comment: Hi , it solved the issue with CompositonHost,but FluentCompositor is still having memory leak.

Comment: @trickymind please update your question to show the code that is using `CreateFluentCompositor()`

Comment: I updated the code could you please check

Comment: i am sharing the full code here : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uturn-beta.appspot.com/o/Fluent%20Compositor.zip?alt=media&token=0d4e911a-a7d4-4e8b-b087-5be631585ba8

Comment: @trickymind "*I updated the code*" - all you did was replace all of your original code with the code I gave you. But you didn't include the code I asked for. Where is the code that is calling `CreateFluentCompositor()`? I have reverted your edit. Please include what I asked for. Don't ask people to look at code on an external site.

Comment: sorry, i thought  it was the function body you asked for, i have added mainwindow.cpp where i load the fluentCompositor.dll and call the CreateFluentCompositor() function.

Comment: @trickymind the signature of `CreateCompositor` in `MainWindow.hpp` does not match the signature of `CreateFluentCompositor()` in `FluentCompositor.cpp`. And now that I see that `MainWindow` expects an `IFluentCompositor*`, I can see that your original code, and my 1st example, were not returning a proper `IFluentCompositor*` to the caller, so I have fixed that in my answer (my 2nd example was already returning the proper pointer).

Comment: let me try it once

Comment: i changed the code to `*compositor = static_cast<IFluentCompositor*>(new(std::nothrow)FluentCompositor);`, but still the memory leak occurs

Comment: i tried to get the exact line number using `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` macro, but it's not showing the line number, where memory leaks occur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235812/discussion-between-trickymind-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: @trickymind there is no memory leak in the code shown. But please fix the signature mismatch, it is causing *undefined behavior*.

Comment: please checked the chat, i have send a screen shot, could you please share the code that you edited, i mean the zip file

Comment: @trickymind everything I've edited is posted here. I have not downloaded the zip